# Bootstrap Media Object - Fixing floated button wrap when media header is long

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position, css-float, user-experience

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap's media object](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#media) styling for our user profiles on a social network of sorts. Pretty standard layout: avatar/logo to the left, title and short description to the right (sorry, not enough rep to provide an image, but see jsfiddle below).

**Where I'm stuck**: I need to include a "follow" button next to the media heading, but I can't figure out how to position it properly to handle a long media heading (the button wraps to the media body).

Suspect I'm heading toward a face-palm moment.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jR3Kf/3/) illustrating both cases.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8 media top-buffer">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="media-object pull-left span2">
            <img class="img-polaroid" src="160x120.jpg">
        </p>
        <div class="media-body span6">
             <h3 class="media-heading">Some Name<i class="icon-circle addToFoo-yes-org"></i> <button class="addToFoo-org btn btn-flat pull-right"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Add to My Foo</button><br />
            </h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note, this is for a prototype and I'm firmly in the n00b category, so pardon my janky markup (particularly the egregious use of the i element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `clearfix` class to `h3.media-heading`.

```
<h3 class="media-heading clearfix">
```

Comment: Open palm, insert face...thanks! For anyone else working with a similar layout, clean it up even more by [attaching the button to the last word in the media heading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246099/attach-font-icon-to-last-word-in-text-string-and-prevent-from-wrapping).