# Attach font icon to last word in text string and prevent from wrapping

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, pseudo-element, font-awesome

I want to attach a Font Awesome icon to the last word in a text string:

```
foo bar●
```

But if a line wrap is required, I want the icon to attach to the last word and have them wrap together:

```
foo
bar●
```

My problem is very similar to:
[Prevent :after element from wrapping to next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100956/prevent-after-element-from-wrapping-to-next-line)

However, the solution assumes I have access to the last word. In my case, the text will be generated dynamically. Is there a css/html-only way to ensure the icon wraps with the last word?

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GmeAq/).

Comment: I can't find a way of doing this in CSS alone as the last word needs linking with the icon. However, it's remarkably easy if you're willing to use a small JS function!

Comment: @nickhar i have the same problem but i cannot use width as the OP has used for the container. if you could help me with this small JS function, it would be helpful.

Comment: Here's my answer to a very similar question that perhaps is overly simple, but it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57815452/491553

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I found you only need to change one line of code for this to work.
Testing on your `.container2` element in jsFiddle, change this

```
.container2:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f111";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

to

```
.container2:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f111";
    display: inline;
}
```

It seems to work with any width I set the container to and will stay connected to what ever `foo` will be.

Comment: Simple but effective. Did the trick for me...thanks! Here's a cleaned up [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jh2j/1/) for anyone else that happens upon this.

Comment: Did you test this cross-browser? Or just in the browser you use?

Comment: @nickhar I haven't done any cross-browser testing (yet) as my immediate use case was for a prototype (on Chrome). I'll be sure to update when I do.

Comment: It works in Trident (IE Framework) browsers, I can seem to get my Gecko browsers to work currently.

Answer (score 15):

I just wanted to point out *why* the change that @Unmocked provided actually works, and it has to do with the [difference between display: inline and display: inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033814/1454806).

To explain, here's a little background on the difference between `block` display and `inline` display.

**Block Display**

`block` elements, in general, are elements which *cause* layout. They receive their own bounding box, and have the ability to push other elements around to some degree in order to fit into the space available within the browser's rendering area. Examples of `block` items include: `h1`, `p`, `ul`, and `table`. Note that each of these items, by default, *starts a new line* and also *ends its own line when closed*. In other words - they fit into a block of text by creating their own paragraph-level section.

**Inline Display**

`inline` elements, in general, are displayed in-line with the text. In other words, they are designed to display *with-**in** the **line** of text*. Examples include `i`, `b`, or `span`. Note that each of these items, by default, *continues with the flow of its surrounding text*, without forcing a newline before or after itself.

Enter the mid-way case...

**Inline-Block Display**

`inline-block` is a hybrid of the above two. In essence, an `inline-block` element *starts* wherever its preceding text leaves off, and attempts to fit into the flow of the document `inline`. However, if it reaches a point where it needs to `wrap`, it will drop to a *new line*, as if it were a `block` element. Subsequent text will then continue immediately following the `inline-block` element, and continue wrapping as normal. This can lead to some strange situations.

Here is an example, to show what I mean. To see it in action, check out [this cssdesk snippet](http://cssdesk.com/daptm).

[image]

In your example, you were setting the `:after` pseudo-element to be `display: inline-block` - which meant that when it happened to extend past the right-most boundary of the wrapping display, it acted like the light-blue text in the example - and wrapped, as a block. When you instead change the `:after` element to `display: inline`, it causes it to act just like any other text - and without whitespace between it and the preceding letters, the word-wrap acts as you wanted it to.

I hope this helps!

**Note:** The other thing which changed between your original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GmeAq/) and the [updated one](http://jsfiddle.net/6jh2j/1/) is the elimination of `white-space` around the text.

In the first fiddle, your HTML looks like:

```
<div class="container2">
    foo bar
</div>
```

While the browser doesn't *display* the spaces before and after the text, it does *contain* the spaces, and when the `:after` element is rendered, it is as if this is happening:

```
<div class="container2"> foo bar :after</div>
```

The browser compresses the multiple spaces into single spaces, but still puts a space between the word `"bar"` and the `:after` element. Just like a space between any other *words*, this will cause the wrap to occur after `"bar"` but before `:after` at a certain width.

In the second fiddle, you are using:

```
<div class="container-wide">foo bar</div>
<div class="container-narrow">foo bar</div>
```

In this case, because there are no spaces trailing the `"foo bar"` strings, the browser renders the `:after` element displayed immediately following the end of the content string. It is as if this is happening:

```
<div class="container-narrow">foo bar:after</div>
```

No break in `inline`-rendered text means no break.

For an example demonstrating this, please see [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/6jh2j/2/) to your jsFiddle.

Comment: This type of answer is the reason I use SO and indeed why it's worth offering a bounty on an unanswered question!

Comment: Ahh - what a great compliment. :) Thank you!

Comment: This is very useful, although to improve clarity, it might be an idea to re-word the first line in the CSSDesk snippet reading "... inline blocks of text ...". As it stands, it reads similarly to the "... inline-block blocks of text ..." (which appears later) and this could cause confusion. Is "blocks of text" a necessary/strict term, or could we call them "chunks" or "sections" of text, for example?

Answer (score 3):

You can use negative margin the width of the icon and css transform. Here a fiddle how to do :

```css
    .container {
        width: 50px;
    }
    .icon-circle {
        background:black;
        height:10px;
        width:10px;
        display: inline-block;   
        margin-left:5px;
    }
    .ANSWER{
        display:block;
        padding-right:15px; /* width of the icon */
    }
    .ANSWER .icon-circle{
        margin-left:-10px;
        transform:translate(15px);
    }
```

```html
    <h4>What we want</h4>
    <div class="this-is-how-it-should-wrap">
        foo bar<i class="icon-circle"></i>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:25px"></div>

    <h4>What happenned</h4>
    <div class="container NORMAL">
        foo bar<i class="icon-circle"></i>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:25px"></div>

    <h3>The answer</h3>
    <div class="container ANSWER">
        foo bar<i class="icon-circle"></i>
    </div>
```

Have a nice day!