# Fontawesome icon prevent newline wrapping

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

how can I prevent a newline to be inserted between a fontawesome icon and the text that is near this icon ?

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pueyY), I have a nbsp, but it is discarded.

In the example below, I don't want a wrap to ever occur between the icon and the word "first", but it can occur between "first" and "second". It doesn't work though, see the fiddle.

```
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;first second
```

It is related to this question, but I can't seem to make it work:

[Attach font icon to last word in text string and prevent from wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246099/attach-font-icon-to-last-word-in-text-string-and-prevent-from-wrapping)

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: I linked to the jsfiddle.net

Comment: Well, it doesn't adds a new line, it goes on a new line because your .test is 20px wide. if you make it bigger it will stay on the same line http://jsfiddle.net/pueyY/3/

Comment: In other words, browser tries to prevent overflow

Comment: But that's what I mean, I don't want it to break at this point, it can break at any other place but this one, I want the icon to always stay near the first word, no matter what.

Comment: Try to add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.test` class

Comment: I edited my question to try to make this point clearer. Basically if there's my icon + firstWord + secondWord, I want it to try to wrap between the first and the second word, rather than between the icon and the first word. I do want it to wrap, just not here

Comment: @EdT. Finally! I was looking so long for a solution and this worked! :D Thanks

Answer (score 30):

Add the CSS: `.fa { display:inline; }`

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mc4ayxf/).

Answer (score 3):

Since the text you're trying to NOT wrap is not inside any element, how would css know where to wrap or not wrap? The width of the jsfiddle .test was 20px, that is the same width (approx) of the icon, so I don't really understand. If you don't want something to wrap, here's one way of doing this, wrap what you want to not wrap inside an inline element, like a span, then add the class you want on that span.

HTML
      
         Abcdef ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

CSS:

```
.test {
    width: 100px; /*20px is too small the icon is 20px (approx) you need more space */
}

.test span {white-space:nowrap}
```

### Demo: http://jsbin.com/rineye/2/edit

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and the cause was that the font awesome icon was automatically being inserted within it's own new p element. I'm not sure why this was happening, but I solved it with this CSS:

`p { display: inline;}`

Make sure you specify which p element you're targeting, so that you don't change every p element on your page!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> below:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.resizable-wrapper {
  border: solid 1px black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.item + .item {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable-wrapper">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>Lorem</span> <!-- lots of these -->
<span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>ipsum</span>
<span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>dolor</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>sit</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>amet,</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>consectetur</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>adipiscing</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>elit.</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>Proin</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>rutrum</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>libero</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>eget</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>justo</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>tempor</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>ornare.</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>Sed</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>aliquam</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>libero</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>sed</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>quam</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>facilisis</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>fringilla.</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>Pellentesque</span> <span class="item"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>habitant</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Actually, it seems to trigger some strange span-width-measuring bug on chrome. But using only one element and the icon as :before works nicely.