# Keep last word and image on same line

Tags: html, css

With CSS, is there a way to break both the last word and the image to a new line at the narrower width?

http://jsfiddle.net/2koc2deo/3/

```css
.text-two {
   width: 125px;
}
.text {
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text text-one">
   <p><a href="#">Customer Service&nbsp;<img src="http://lorempixel.com/15/15/" alt=""></a>
</div>

<div class="text text-two">
   <p><a href="#">Customer Service&nbsp;<img src="http://lorempixel.com/15/15/" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think , you can use `::last-word` tag in css3 .

Comment: `::last-word` isn't a thing. Unless you polyfill it somehow. Here's a related question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9268386/221867

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a negative right margin to the `<a>` elements, to match the image width.
This prevents the images from triggering a line wrap.
The line will only wrap if the text itself doesn't fit.

This works best in contexts where the right overflow of the container will still be visible.

```css
.text {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.text-two {
  width: 118px;
}

.text a {
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text text-one">
  <p><a href="#">Customer Service&nbsp;<img src="https://fakeimg.pl/15x15/" alt=""></a></p>
</div>

<div class="text text-two">
  <p><a href="#">Customer Service&nbsp;<img src="https://fakeimg.pl/15x15/" alt=""></a></p>
</div>
```

This solution is inspired by [Beauceron's answer to "Attach font icon to last word in text string and prevent from wrapping"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246099/attach-font-icon-to-last-word-in-text-string-and-prevent-from-wrapping#answer-30741224)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the above to work.  I fixed mine by putting a span around the last word and the image and use `white-space: nowrap;`.

Here's a fiddle:

```css
.text-two {
   width: 125px;
}

.text {
   font-size: 16px;
}

.no-wrap {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="text text-two">
   <p>Customer <span class="no-wrap">Service <img src="http://lorempixel.com/15/15/" alt=""></span></p>
</div>
```